# ASP.NET website update assemblies references without modifying .refresh file

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget-package-restore

My solution file contains a website project and some library projects. My website project is depending on these library projects and some other nuget packages. I have to build my **.sln** by MS Build. By executing nuget.exe all dependencies are loaded, but their references not updated to packages folder. When I google my problem I found the following solution.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/823752/ASP-NET-Website-Project-External-Assembly-Referenc.
But it did not solve my problem as I do not want to keep bin folder and I also do not want to keep the **.refresh** files of all the DLL. I need to load all external dependencies and referenced automatically, when I build .sln file.

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> ASP.NET website update assemblies references without modifying .refresh file

If I understand you correct, you can add a class library project to the solution, and add reference to the class library project to your website. Then, add the nuget in the class library, not the website project.

Then you could use nuget.exe update those nuget packages for the solution, like:

```
nuget.exe update "<YourWebsitePath>\WebSite1.sln"
```

In this way, When your build website, it pulls in all the class libraries' dependencies in turn.

If I am not understand you correct, please let me know for free and you can share a simple sample about your question, so that we could understand it more clearly.

Hope this helps.